# Laravel - Calling a method on null & returning false if null

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I have ACL set up with laravel. I have the following helper:

```
function user($user_id = null)
{
    if (!$user_id) return Auth::user();
    return User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
}
```

I have this helper function so I don't have to type the long `Auth::user()`.

Here's the problem. I have ACL set up so when I do something like the following in my model and the user is not logged in, I get an error.

```
if (user()->can('edit-blog')) {
   echo 'you can edit blog!';
}
```

This is the error if the user is not logged in:

> Call to a member function can() on null

Now, I have the following code everywhere in my site. I am using ACL in almost every view and model and controller. I don't want to have to do something like the following just to not get the error.

```
if (user() && user()->can('edit-blog')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

How can I return false if there is a "null" error or an exception?

** What I have tried **

I have tried `try/catch` but it does not do anything:

```
  try {
    if (!$user_id) return Auth::user();
    return User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    return false;
}
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: You need to check then call. So store the result of the `user()` call to a variable, then check it and use to invoke a `can()` method.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, checking and calling. I was wondering if there is a way to just call and if the user is not logged in it can automatically return false but guess not. Thanks.

Comment: It's not what you're doing: I suggested to store the result of the call into a variable, so that you did not query db twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user is logged in before calling can

```
if(Auth::check() && user()->can('edit-post')){
    Return true;
 }else{
    Return false;
 }
```